# Regex any number mid-string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using javascript to quickly validate a specific url that can have multiple outcomes, i'm trying to use regex for this.

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("[0-9]");

var x = checkPage(); 
// returns: "/appl/coursemenu/chapter/ (a number here) /"

switch(x){
    case "/appl/coursemenu/chapter/"+regexNum+"/":
        chapter();
        break;
}
```

So the basic idea is that it is that specific url, but it has to have a number at the end. (and a "/" )

Thanks

[EDIT]

I added a JSFiddle to show what exactly is going wrong in my code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UNjU/1/)

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: @PratikJoshi I added a JSFiddle to show what is going on, it needs to check for any set of numbers where the regexNum variable is placed, this could range anywhere from 0 to 99999

Comment: You properly tell what input You want to give ,and what output you want ,everything is messed up and unclear.

Comment: @PratikJoshi , the function checkPage(); returns a string that starts with "/appl/coursemenu/chapter/" then any set of numbers and then another "/" (example: "/appl/coursemenu/chapter/16/") , all I need is the switch case to return true and run chapter(); when it gets a string like the example I gave above

Comment: Why must you have a trailing slash? At the very least it should be optional: `\d+\/?$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("/appl/coursemenu/chapter/[0-9]/");

var x = checkPage(); 
// returns: "/appl/coursemenu/chapter/ (a number here) /"

if(regexNum.test(x)){
    chapter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a number (combination of digits) at the end, followed by a slash.:

```
"/appl/coursemenu/chapter/123/".test(/\d+\/$/) --> true (123/)
```

Regex: `/\d+\/$/`

The `$` matches end of line.
The `\/` matches a `/`
The `\d+` matches `0` or `99999` etc.

Comment: Its close, but the number could be any set of numbers, it could range from 0 to 99999

Comment: @Paradoxis Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another crazy idea if you want to keep `switch` statement:

```
switch (true) {
    case /appl\/coursemenu\/chapter\/\d+\/$/.test(x):
        chapter();
        break;

    ...
}
```